# How can apply 4 different tooltip onto a single image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone help me that how can apply 4 different type of tooltips onto a single image?
When someone mouse over on image at top bottom left and right, at that time 4 different tooltip should be displayed.

Here, I have put example what I need. It's in Flash but I want without Flash.
http://www.lavasa.com/high/

If you have any idea regarding same please share with me.

Comment: The example you give is not quite the same problem if you are referring to the way the background moves as this can be achieved using the mouse location relative to the size of the browser window.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have three options.

1. Doing some work and displaying a tooltip 'manually', i.e. a floating div using javascript or something, there are probably a bunch of libraries for doing this.
2. Split your image into four, and provide a title (which will be displayed as a tooltiop of mouse is hovering) for each.
3. Do it old school with a `<map>`.

An example using `<map>`:

```
<img src="trees.gif" usemap="#green" border="0">
<map name="green">
  <area title="Save" shape="polygon" coords="19,44,45,11,87,37,82,76,49,98" href="http://www.trees.com/save.html">
  <area title="Furniture" shape="rect" coords="128,132,241,179" href="http://www.trees.com/furniture.html">
  <area title="Plantations" shape="circle" coords="68,211,35" href="http://www.trees.com/plantations.html">
</map>
```

(Blatantly stolen from http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml which was the first google hit, only added the 'title'-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You could add 4 transparent images over your image and apply hover methods in them.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for an imagemap with tooltips.  Here is a quick example I can find, the demo you want to see is at the bottom of the page.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Answer (score 0):

Well image map also struct me.
But these is another simpler method without having to write custom javascript. Just cut the image into 4 different parts and apply tooltip to each or simple `<img alt="txt for north-west"/>` will show some image tooltip.